# How would I export values from measurements with Influxdb 1.6 with certain formatting to a CSV

Tags: csv, export, export-to-csv, influxdb, influxql

I have measurements that are saved from MQTT every second, I need to export data to CSV in order to do reports. Some of the exports should be averaged over an hour, others over the day and I might have to adjust the time period after seeing the results.

I have multiple databases (each area on its own database), each database have the following measurements:

- blue_active_power_(Watts)
- blue_current_(A)
- blue_energy_counter_(Watt-minute)
- blue_power_factor
- blue_total_(kWh)
- blue_volts
- geyser_active_power_(Watts)
- geyser_energy_counter_(Watt-minute)
- geyser_relay
- red_active_power_(Watts)
- red_current_(A)
- red_energy_counter_(Watt-minute)
- red_power_factor
- red_total_(kWh)
- red_volts
- yellow_active_power_(Watts)
- yellow_current_(A)
- yellow_energy_counter_(Watt-minute)
- yellow_power_factor
- yellow_total_(kWh)
- yellow_volts

I don't mind having separate scripts for each measurement export.

The date/time should also be in the following format: "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM"

Running the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM "blue_total_(kWh)" ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
```

I get the response of:
name: blue_total_(kWh)
time                value

---

1682865656000000000 7515806.2

This is my first time using StackOverflow, please advise if I need to add or change anything to make it easier to understand.

I have tried various methods of formatting the date and time, most of which are for v1.8 upward.
I am limited to version 1.6 as it is running on a raspberry pi as the server.

Some of my attemps (shell and influxdb cli):

```
influx -database 'bakery' -format "csv" -execute 'SELECT MEAN(value) AS hourly_avg INTO "/mnt/chromeos/removable/Extended/Code/bakery_blue_current.csv" FROM MEAN(blue_current_(A)) WHERE time >= 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z AND time <= 2023-03-31T23:59:59Z GROUP BY time(1h)'
```

```
#!/bin/bash

influx -database "bakery" -format "csv" -execute 'SELECT * FROM "blue_volts" WHERE time >= '2022-12-01T00:00:00Z' AND time <= '2023-03-31T23:59:59Z'
```

I have so many script files saved, none of which give me the result I need.